# Snowflake UDF & Javascript - Issue with JavaScript compilation error: Uncaught SyntaxError

Tags: javascript, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Disclaimer:  I'm new to JavaScript & new to writing JavaScript UDFs in Snowflake.

I'm attempting to build a UDF which will "clean" the string of any characters where the ascii code is not between 32 & 127.  When I attempt to use this function, I get the error:

```
Reason:
SQL Error [100131] [P0000]: JavaScript compilation error: Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after
argument list in CLEAN at '    FOR (i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {' position 13
```

After searching around for what in the syntax could be causing this problem, I'm no further along. The value being input is a length 3 string, with the following ascii codes: 0, 13, 0

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION clean(value STRING)
    RETURNS string LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
    AS 
    $$ 
    var i = 0;
    var letter = "";
    var newValue = "";
    FOR (i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
        letter = value[i].charCodeAt(0)
        IF ( letter >= 32 && letter <= 126) {
            newValue += value[i];
        } elseif (letter = 0) {
            newValue += value[i];
        }
    }
RETURN newValue
$$;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

1) JavaScript is a case sensitive so keywords like FOR, IF and WHILE need to be lowercased. (Thanks to @waldente for that answer)

Also:

2) Change all references to the input parameter from lowercase `value`  to uppercase `VALUE`. For example change `value.length` in your for loop to `VALUE.length`

In the documentation on JavaScript UDFs there is [this part](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/udf-js.html#introductory-example) that says:

> Note that the JavaScript code must refer to the input parameter names as all upper-case, even if the names are not uppercase in the SQL code

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work. I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Make FOR, IF and RETURN lowercase

Comment: @waldente is right - JavaScript is case sensitive so that will probably fix your issue. I'll update my answer to include that